# Definition and equivalence of quadratic forms: what should be uniform way to understand them?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I came across definitions of quadratic forms with little modifications. Let $V$ be vector space of finite dimension over $K$. A quadratic form $Q$  on $V$ is defined as

(1) A map $Q:V\rightarrow K$ with $Q(av)=a^2Q(v)$ and $(u,v)\mapsto Q(u+v)-Q(u)-Q(v)$ is bilinear.

(1') A map $Q:V\rightarrow K$ with $Q(av)=a^2Q(v)$ and $(u,v)\mapsto \frac{Q(u+v)-Q(u)-Q(v)}{2}$ is bilinear.

The only modification here is factor $2$, which plays a role when Char$F=2$.

**Q.1** If we accept definition (1), will it make changes in some standard theorems on quadratic forms, especially equivalence of quadratic theorems, whatever characteristic of the field is?

Let us fix a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ of finite dimension, with no restriction on Char $K$.

> Quadratic forms $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ on $V$ are equivalent if there is $T\in GL(V)$ with $Q_1(Tv)=Q_2(v)$.
>
> Bilinear forms $(\cdot,\cdot)_1$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)_2$ are equivalent if $\exists$ $T\in GL(V)$ with $(Tv,Tw)_1=(v,w)_2$.

I have never gone in depth of both the objects. I want to know following:

**Q.2** *Is there any relation between equivalence of quadratic forms and of bilinear forms? What I mean here is, if we know classification of one of these two objects, do we get classification of others?*

Comment: Consider the value of $(v,v)$ under your two definitions: $(1)$ gives $2Q(v)$ and $(1')$ gives $Q(v)$ - so if you can divide by $2$ you can get a quadratic form from any bilinear form (and a bilinear form from every quadratic form). Characteristic $2$ is different and can't be treated the same as the other cases.

Comment: http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-39